# If $ n \le m$, then is there a closed immersion from $\mathbb{P}^n_k \to \mathbb{P}^m_k $ between projective spaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Literally,

Q. If $ n \le m$, then is there a closed immersion from $\mathbb{P}^n_k \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m_k $ between projective spaces?

This question originates from trial to understanding next theorem(Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Theorem 14.130)

**Theorem 14.130**. Let $k$ be an infinite field, let $X$ be a $k$-scheme which is projective and smooth over  $k$, and let $d:=\operatorname{dim}X$. Then there exists a closed immersion $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{2d+1}_k$.

Since $X$ is projective, there is a closed immersion $X \to \mathbb{P}^N_k$ for some $N$. So, if $N \le 2d+1$, then if our question is true, there is a closed immersion $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{2d+1}_k$.

Is the question true?

First attempt : In liu's Algebraic geometry book, p.53, Lemma 3.41., he states that

**Lemma 3.41.** Let $B=A[T_0,\cdots T_n]/I$ is a homogeneous algebra over $A$ (;i.e., the $I$ is a homogeneous ideal). Then $\operatorname{Proj}B$ is isomorphic to a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_A$

Now return to our question. We are given $n\le m$. I'm trying to show that

$$ f: k[T_0 \cdots T_m] \to k[T_0, \cdots T_n]$$

$$  T_{n+1}, \cdots , T_m \mapsto 1$$

(or $$ T_{n+1}, \cdots , T_m \mapsto 0$$)

, is surjective homomorphism of rings with homogeneous kernel.

Then $k[T_0, \cdots ,T_n] \cong k[T_0, \cdots, T_m] /\operatorname{ker}f$ and so, $\mathbb{P}^n_k := \operatorname{Proj}(k[T_0, \cdots , T_n]) $ is isomorphic to a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^m_k$

But I stucked at showing the homogeneity of the $\operatorname{ker}f$. Is it true?

Anyone helps?

Comment: Hint: if $n \leq m$, can you think of a way to embed $k^n$ as a closed subspace of $k^m$?

Comment: If you're sending the $T_i\mapsto 0$ for $n+1\leq i\leq m$, then the kernel of the ring map is generated by these $T_i$. These generators are all homogeneous (of degree $1$), so the ideal they generate is homogeneous. If you were to send the $T_i\mapsto 1$, then the kernel is generated by the differences $T_i-T_j$; these generators are still homogeneous of degree $1$.

Comment: @Dave :  Oh really? I'll check it. Thank you for comment!

Comment: That is, $V(T_{n+1},\dots,T_m)\subset\mathbb P^m$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: Uhm. Unexpected approach.  In fact, I'm not familier to the vanishing scheme(?). I'll study associated data. Thank you.